# how to find the activity idle time of a person using sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, gaps-and-islands

`worker` table keeping track of all the work a worker  undertakes in a given day. How do you query that table to find out the time when he did not have any work both time and timestamps when he was free.

So the table may have a record when he picks up his first work and then he picks another and then drops both of them. After a while he picks up a few more which again is recorded in the table.

So with all that how do you find the data when he does not have any work

Table: `worker`

```
  worker_id | task_id |      start_ts       |       end_ts        
 -----------|---------|---------------------|--------------------- 
          1 |       1 | 2019-27-10 03:14:07 | 2019-27-10 03:20:07 
          1 |       2 | 2019-27-10 03:19:07 | 2019-27-10 03:25:07 
          1 |       3 | 2019-27-10 03:18:07 | 2019-27-10 05:20:07 
          2 |       1 | 2019-27-10 06:14:07 | 2019-27-10 06:20:07 
          3 |       2 | 2019-27-10 06:19:07 | 2019-27-10 06:25:07 
          4 |       3 | 2019-27-10 06:18:07 | 2019-27-10 07:20:07
```

Comment: Can a worker really handle multiple tasks at the same time? What exactly is the output you want based on your sample data?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. This is the test data I have given here. Please don't go into the sematics of it. But I am looking for the same logic

Answer (score 0):

You can split the data into the individual timestamps.  Then assign `+1` to start times and `-1` to end times (plus one second).  The cumulative sum of this value tells you how many tasks someone has starting at that time.

So the final step is filtering where the value is 0:

```
with t as (
      select worker_id, start_ts as ts, 1 as inc
      from work
      union all
      select worker_id, end_ts + interval '1 second' as ts, -1 as inc
      from work
     ),
     t2 as (
      select t.worker, t.ts,
             sum(sum(t.inc)) over (partition by t.worker_id) as num_tasks,
             lead(t.ts) over (partition by t.worker, t.ts) as next_ts
      from t
      group by t.worker, t.ts
     )
select t2.*
from t2
where num_tasks = 0;
```